# Incorrect syntax near 'CAST' in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table pin_mst below

[image]

but the following query is showing error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.
```

.. plz help.

```
SELECT TOP CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(3)) PIN_ID from pin_mst
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to cast the `PIN_ID`? or what? Why not `SELECT TOP 1 PIN_ID from pin_mst` or `SELECT TOP 1 CAST(PIN_ID AS VARCHAR(3)) from pin_mst`??

Comment: What did you expect the query to do? You're casting `1` to a `VARCHAR(3)`, but you're also asking for `TOP` which expects a numeric argument.

Comment: Yes. Please describe what you're actually trying to do, including the expected result set that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT TOP 1 PIN_ID 
FROM pin_mst
```

or this -

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(3)), 
    PIN_ID 
FROM pin_mst
```

Answer (score 7):

You must enter how many rows you want when using `TOP`. For example 10 in the example below.

```
SELECT TOP 10 CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(3)) PIN_ID from pin_mst
```

Although there is no need for any casting in that query, you could just write

```
SELECT TOP 10 '1' PIN_ID from pin_mst
```

Or if `PIN_ID` is actually a column you want back and not an alias and the casting stuff was just the top statement.

```
SELECT TOP 1 PIN_ID FROM pin_mst
```